# How do I use the transform CSS properties in Choreographer JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I'm trying to use Christine Cha's Choreorapher JS to have scrolling animations on a website I'm designing/developing. I want to rotate a letter, but this code I have wrote doesn't work. The other animations (just changes in opacity at the moment) work perfectly fine, but anything that starts with "transform" doesn't do anything. I looked at the documentation website to see if I did anything wrong, but my code looks essentially identical to [Cha's](https://christinecha.github.io/choreographer-js/).

The weird thing is, when I scroll through the website with the Dev Tools open, it looks as if it should be working—there are no obvious syntax errors, and Choreographer looks like it's doing what it should be doing. But nothing's happening. I can't post images yet, [but here's a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6uBG.jpg) (I stopped the recording a little early before it loops, but it stops at 90 degrees, as intended).

Here's the relevant code I have. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
let choreographer = new Choreographer({
    animations: [

        //rotate letter — this is the one that doesn't work
        { range: [50, 150], selector: '.char1', type: 'scale', style: 'transform:rotateZ', from: 0, to: 90, unit: 'deg' },

        // scroll — this and below are fine
        { range: [-1, 150], selector: '#scroll-down', type: 'scale', style: 'opacity', from: 1, to: 0},

        // fade in fixed elements/header
        { range: [150, 250], selector: 'header', type: 'scale', style: 'opacity', from: 0, to: 1},
        { range: [150, 250], selector: '#burger-container', type: 'scale', style: 'opacity', from: 0, to: 1},
        { range: [150, 250], selector: '#bottom-right', type: 'scale', style: 'opacity', from: 0, to: 1}
    ]
})

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    choreographer.runAnimationsAt(window.pageYOffset)
})
```

HTML:

```
<section id="splash">
    <h1 class="title" aria-label="boy detectives">
        <span class="char1" aria-hidden="true">b</span>
        <span class="char2" aria-hidden="true">o</span>
        <span class="char3" aria-hidden="true">y</span>
        <span class="char4" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
        <span class="char5" aria-hidden="true">d</span>
        <span class="char6" aria-hidden="true">e</span>
        <span class="char7" aria-hidden="true">t</span>
        <span class="char8" aria-hidden="true">e</span>
        <span class="char9" aria-hidden="true">c</span>
        <span class="char10" aria-hidden="true">t</span>
        <span class="char11" aria-hidden="true">i</span>
        <span class="char12" aria-hidden="true">v</span>
        <span class="char13" aria-hidden="true">e</span>
        <span class="char14" aria-hidden="true">s</span>
    </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: ridge show your html code

Answer (score 1):

The code in your inspector says you are transforming the `rotateX` property, but your Javascript says `transform:rotateZ`. Maybe just a copy+paste bug.

The other thing is that you cannot transform an element that is not `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. `<spans>` are `inline` so you will have to add an extra CSS rule to those elements.

```
#splash span { 
  display: inline-block;
}
```